# Understanding etoolbox \ifdefempty and \ifdefvoid

Tags: macros, tex-core, etoolbox

I am trying to understand the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) `\ifdefempty` and `\ifdefvoid` macros. The documentation says that `\ifdefempty`

> Expands to true if the control sequence is defined and is a
>   parameterless macro whose replacement text is empty, and to false
>   otherwise.

Similarly `\ifdefvoid`

> Expands to true if the control sequence is undefined, if is a macro
>   whose meaning is `\relax`, or a parameterless macro whose replacement
>   text is empty, and to false otherwise.

From these descriptions I thought that `\def\myempty{}`, `\def\myrelax{\relax}`, and `\def\myemptyempty{\myempty}` would all be both "empty" and "void", but `\def\myempty{}` is the only one that is either "empty" or "void". What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\myempty{}
\def\myrelax{\relax}
\def\myemptyempty{\myempty}


\ifdefempty{\myempty}{Empty}{Not empty}

\ifdefempty{\myrelax}{Empty}{Not empty}

\ifdefempty{\myemptyempty}{Empty}{Not empty}

\ifdefvoid{\myempty}{Void}{Not void}

\ifdefvoid{\myrelax}{Void}{Not void}

\ifdefvoid{\myemptyempty}{Void}{Not void}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `\<cs>` passes the first two tests of `\ifdefempty` (is defined and is parameterless), the next test - is the replacement text empty - is performed within `\etb@ifdefempty`. This test checks whether the `\meaning` of `\<cs>` is "blank":

```
\def\etb@ifdefempty#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\ifblank
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter{%
  \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}}
```

The "blank" here is checked against a `\strip@prefix` of the `\meaning` of `#1`. This just strips the `macro:->` part from the output of `\meaning` (so `macro:->\relax` is changed to `\relax`). So, in the case of

- `\myempty`, the check is `\ifblank{}` which is true.
- `\myrelax`, the check is `\ifblank{\relax}` which is false.
- `\myemptyempty`, the check is `\ifblank{\myempty}`, which is false.

The following updated version of `\ifdefempty` actually shows you what the comparisons are performed against:

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ifdefempty}[1]{
  {\ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1\quad}%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\ifdefmacro{#1}
       {\ifdefparam{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\etb@ifdefempty{#1}}}
       {\@secondoftwo}}}
\makeatother
```

The inner-workings of `\ifdefvoid` is similar since it uses the same inner-most function for testing, namely `\etb@ifdefempty`. The following updated version of `\ifdefvoid` highlights what the tests are performed against:

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ifdefvoid}[1]{%
  {\ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1\quad}%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\ifdefmacro{#1}
       {\ifdefparam{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\etb@ifdefempty{#1}}}
       {\@secondoftwo}}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 16):

With `\def\myrelax{\relax}` macro `\myrelax` is a parameterless macro with replacment text `\relax`. You get a command sequence with meaning `\relax` with `\let`:

```
\let\myrelax\relax
```

Also `\def\myemptyempty{\myempty}` defines a parameterless macro `\myemptyempty` that is not empty, whose replacement text is `\myemptyempty`. There is `\edef` that expands the replacement text first:

```
\edef\myemptyempty{\myempty}
```

Summary:

`\ifdefempty` catches the case:

- `\myempty`: `\def\myempty{}`

and `\ifdefvoid` the cases:

- `\UnDeFiNeDCoMmAnD`
- `\myrelax`: `\let\myrelax\relax`
- `\myempty`: `\def\myempty{}`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than digging into the internals, let's just parse the documented behavior.

> `\ifdefempty`: Expands to true if the control sequence is defined and is a parameterless macro whose replacement text is empty, and to false otherwise.

This means that `\ifdefempty{\cs}` tests whether `\cs` is a macro (i.e. a non-primitive control sequence that is expandable) taking no parameters, and that its first-level expansion is empty.  That is, it should have been created via

```
\def\cs{}
\edef\cs{<stuff expanding to empty text>}
\let\cs<control sequence for which \ifdefempty{} is true>
```

> `\ifdefvoid`: Expands to true if the control sequence is undefined, if is a macro whose meaning is \relax, or a parameterless macro whose replacement text is empty, and to false otherwise.

This extends the test of `\ifdefempty` to include control sequences that are undefined (as opposed to primitive and unexpandable, which are not void in the sense of this test), or equivalent to `\relax`.  The use of the word "macro" in the latter connection is unfortunate, since they are not macros in the technical sense (not being expandable).  Such a control sequence should have been created via:

```
<any of the above for \ifdefempty>
\let\cs\relax
\csname cs\endcsname %If \cs were previously undefined, this makes it \relax
```

or, of course, having *never* been created and thus remaining undefined.