# Producing an empty argument

Tags: macros

I've been using Herbert's answer in [Check for empty macro argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89365/check-for-empty-macro-argument) to check if an argument is empty. I was wondering if it is possible to expand Herbert's solution to also detect if a macro argument is `\empty`. Failing this, I was hoping to learn a way to set a macro in so that `\ifempty` will behave like I want. The following code shows that `\ifempty` correctly detects an empty macro argument, but does not consider `\empty` to be an empty argument. Then, I give a couple of unsuccessful attempts to define an empty macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ifempty#1{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifempty{}{1. empty}{1. nonempty}

\ifempty{\empty}{2. empty}{2. nonempty}

\def\z%
\ifempty{\z}{3. empty}{3. nonempty}

\def\z{}%
\ifempty{\z}{4. empty}{4. nonempty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what is required for 'empty macros'. For example, are we looking for exactly one expansion or is it 'exhaustive': what should `\def\a{\b}\def\b{}\ifempty{\b}` yield? Can we assume one token in the input for a command? Is `\def\a#1{stuff}\ifempty{\a}` a danger?

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110726/understanding-etoolbox-ifdefempty-and-ifdefvoid

Comment: @JosephWright Some context: I have been using the `\ifempty` macro within commands, and it has met my needs. Recently I wanted to test if a string option from `kvoptions` was empty. According to the documentation, "The initial contents of the macro can be given by the first optional argument <init>. The default is empty." It seems to me that "empty" means `\@empty`, and I would like to be able to test this. For my particular needs, the command does not need to be particularly robust, and a simple elaboration to the the case I just described would be nice.

Comment: It seems like there should be a command of the form `\def\z<???>` that will make `\z` trigger the `\ifempty` macro.

Answer (score 1):

Detokenized `\empty` of course is not empty. Short comment to the four examples.

1. Is as expected.
2. Is nonempty as it was said at the beginning.
3. You are defining `\z`, after which should be string `%
   \ifempty`. The definition is erroneus, but never used. Then there is `{3. empty}{3. nonempty}` and it is written as an ordinary text.
4. Now `\z` is properly defined, but `z` is of course not empty.

If you want simply compare equivalence of macros, `\ifx` may be more suitable for you.

Comment: Would some of the macros from `etoolbox` help?

Comment: I can use `\ifx` to compare an argument to `\@empty`: this was actually why I was trying to find a command to set a variable in such a way that it triggers `\ifempty`. I want to use `\ifempty{\z}` instead of `\ifx\z\@empty` because I think the former is clearer.