# Correct Use of \ifcsempty Command

Tags: etoolbox

The intent of this command sequence is to loop through the 3 options and display either the book/page or instrument no. for each. A excternal programatic function will validate that there is either a book/page of Instrument for each option. I still do not have a feel for how to effective use the available commands but if I can get this going I can build from here.

```
\newcommand\ErDeedABookA {}
\newcommand\ErDeedAPageA {}
\newcommand\ErDeedAInstA {I113}
\newcommand\ErDeedBBookB {B211}
\newcommand\ErDeedBPageB {P212}
\newcommand\ErDeedBInstB {}
\newcommand\ErDeedCBookC {}
\newcommand\ErDeedCPageC {}
\newcommand\ErDeedCInstC {I313}

\newcommand\LP {A}
\newcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Book#1}
\newcommand\AB {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname}

\newcounter{zz}
\setcounter{zz}{1}
\renewcommand\thezz{\Alph{zz}}
\renewcommand\LP {\thezz}
\newcommand\EBI {}
\newcommand\EBB {}
\newcommand\EBP {}

\whiledo {\value{zz} < 4}%
{%
\ifcsempty {\AB}
{\renewcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Inst#1}\renewcommand\EBI {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname} Instrument No. \EBI}
{\renewcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Book#1}\renewcommand\EBB {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname} Deed Book \EBB, 
\renewcommand\Er[1]{ErDeed#1Page#1}\renewcommand\EBP {\csname\Er\LP\endcsname} Page \EBP}

  \stepcounter {zz}%
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your fragment into a complete minimal document. (And you can format code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` icon.)

Comment: One issue you are going to have is that `\AB` is a macro, the corresponding control sequence (CS) is `AB`.

Comment: I tried using \ifcsstring and \ifdefstring but could not get it to test for a null value for \AB?

Comment: @PaulHill see this related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110726/understanding-etoolbox-ifdefempty-and-ifdefvoid